# Java mail is not supporting foreign languages

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail

I need to send HTML having content in different languages. my configuration are :

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;    boundary="----=_Part_18_19002270.1337852743826"

------=_Part_18_19002270.1337852743826 Content-Type: text/html; charset=Cp1252 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

and in mail am getting all characters as `?`. Can anybody suggest me how to set encoding so that i could get mail in proper language.

Thanks

**found the solution:)**

```
 MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(bodyText, "UTF-8");


        htmlPart.setText(bodyText, "utf-8");
        htmlPart.setHeader("Content-Type","text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"");
        htmlPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");
```

Still am not able to encode Subject line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of code might help you. :)

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setSubject("yourSubject", "UTF-8"); // here you specify your subject encoding
msg.setContent("yourBody", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

msg.setFrom("senderAddress");
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, "recieverAddress");
Transport.send(msg);
```

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setSubject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is the method I've used to set the encoding of subject line.

Comment: I got "?UTF-8?B?w5jCp8OZwoTDmMKqw5jCs8OYwqzDmcKKw5nChCDDmcKBw5nCiiDDmcKF?=
 =?UTF-8?B?w5nChsOYwqfDmcKBw5jCs8OYwqkgw5jCp8OZwoTDmMKjw5nChMOYwrnDmMKn?=
 =?UTF-8?B?w5jCqCDDmMKnw5nChMOYwqPDmcKIw5nChMOZworDmcKFw5jCqMOZworDmMKp?=
 =?UTF-8?B?IMOZwoTDmMK0w5jCscOZwoPDmMKpTWNEb25hbGTDosKAwplz?=" wheres expected is Arebic

Comment: also set your property `props.setProperty("charset","utf-8");`

Comment: Where are you viewing the email?

Comment: which props?? and am usng gmail to view mail

Comment: property file which you assign to the `session`

Comment: I set  props.setProperty("charset", "utf-8"); and  message.setSubject(emailMessage.getSubject(),"UTF-8"); still same result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11686/discussion-between-romi-and-hashimr)

Comment: Hey sorry had to leave. Nudge me when you come back.

Answer (score 2):

Convert whole html File read string to UniCode
I used the below code to convert Whole HTML File read as String using FileUtils

`String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/path/to/the/HTMLfile"), "UTF-8")`

I was trying to send an Email in Chinese, Arabic, Japanese and Spanish. So while sending I was unable to figure it out while setting Content in MimeMessage and MimeMultipart

So, I read the whole file as a string and then check whether the character lies between 1-128 i.e. ASCII equivalent characters (Numeric Special Characters Space etc..) that belong to ASCII. I retained them in the string and rest all characters are converted to Unicode

Function to convert html file string to Unicode string and is then set in mime body part and mime multipart. Hope it is very clear

```
public String convertToUniCode(String yourHTMLBodyStr) {
        String str = "<div>Chinese 你好嗎 English How are you Japanese お元気ですか Arabic كيف حالك Spanish  cómo estás</div>";
        String[] codePointAt = new String[str.length()];

        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            int charactercode = Character.codePointAt(str, j);
            if (charactercode > 0 && charactercode < 128) {
                codePointAt[j] = String.valueOf(str.charAt(j));
            } else {
                codePointAt[j] = "&#" + String.valueOf(charactercode) + ";";
            }

        }

        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < codePointAt.length; i++) {
            strBuilder.append(codePointAt[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("New String :: " + strBuilder.toString());
    }
```

Output(Unicode String) with &# Like &#16003 :

New String :: Chinese 你好嗎 English How are you  Japanese お元気ですか Arabic كيف حالك Spanish  cómo estás

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
String htmlUnicodeStr = convertToUniCode(yourHTMLBodyStr);

msg.setSubject(UniCodeSubject, "UTF-8"); // here you specify your subject encoding

Multipart emailMimeMultipart;
MimeBodyPart messageBody = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBody.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(htmlUnicodeStr, "text/html")));
    emailMimeMultipart.addBodyPart(messageBody);
//Add UTF-8 In MimeMultiPart While Setting Content and Transport.Send()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch `charset=Cp1252` to `charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: exactly. I used  MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(bodyText, "charset=UTF-8"); but while printing am getting charset=Cp1252 :(

Comment: What about setText method? Do you pass an encoding there?

Comment: No , I am not using setText() , should i set encoding here?

Comment: MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(bodyText, "UTF-8");
        htmlPart.setText(bodyText, "UTF-8");, but nothing changed :(